# Input time delay in control system using pade approximation

Tags: matlab

I have a transfer function sys = sys1 * sys2. I want to input time delay in my system but instead of using exp(-0.6s) * sys , i want to approximate the exp(-0.6*s) using pade. So the code i wrote is

But for some reason, the step plot i get is not correct. Have I made a mistake somewhere?

I ve seen some examples on mathwork but I dont want to use pade to approximate the entire system, only the exponential part. Also some people use series(sys, padesys) or even convolution instead of sys*padesys

```
a = 1.038108;
sys1 = tf(13.47826, [1 a/23]);
sys2 = tf([29.677 1.33949], [1 400]);
sys = sys1 * sys2

[num2, den2] = pade(0.6, 3);
padesys = tf(num2, den2);
sys_delayed = padesys * sys;
step(sys_delayed);
```